# Windows 8 lowering down volume of applications when it detects communications - yet setting is set to "Do nothing."

Tags: windows-8, audio, skype

Title pretty much explains everything. In my sound settings under the "Communications" tab, I have Windows set to "Do nothing" when communications are detected, yet it still lowers other applications. I'm using Skype for communications, and apparently from what I've read online, Skype itself doesn't lower the volume of other applications. All of my sound drivers are up to date as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT - I figured it out and I'm not sure how to close this question. Basically I have an MSI G45 Z87 motherboard, and I'm using the built-in audio. Some sort of "sound blaster" program was installed with my drivers which was the culprit - I just turned off every setting and it seemed to work. Typing this out in case anyone is Googling the same problem I had.

Comment: Welcome to superuser! Good you found a solution. You can post an answer to your own question and then accept this one. Like that the question is correctly closed.